# Microsoft Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

The Error States:

```
Run-time error '94'
Invalid use of Null
```

Options to: (End) (Debug) (Help)

I hit Debug

Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications opens window for
(Calculate Functions Code)

(Issue Below)

```
'Add Leap Year determination
    Dim blnIsLeapYear As Boolean
    Dim intYear As Integer
    blnIsLeapYear = False
    intYear = YY
    If (intYear Mod 4 = 0) Then
        blnIsLeapYear = True
        If (intYear Mod 100 = 0) Then
            If (intYear Mod 400 <> 0) Then
                blnIsLeapYear = False
```

`IntYear = YY` is highlighted in YELLOW. I have no idea how to fix the issue.

Comment: What is YY supposed to be? It is currently null - [error 94](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/invalid-use-of-null-error-94)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the "End if" in your code.

Remember the if structure is:

If something then
Do what you need
End if.

for example:

```
If (intYear Mod 4 = 0) Then 
    blnIsLeapYear = True
End if
```

Another problem is that you are assigning the YY to intYear in intYear = YY , but you never created of populated the YY.

Comment: we probably see only a fraction of the code. If YY would not be defined it would not raise runtime error 94. This can only happen if YY contains `null`, which is a value that usually comes from a database query.

Comment: If `YY` is an undeclared variable, VBA will treat it as an empty variant which will then correspond to Null at the line which triggers the error, `IntYear = YY`.  Since `intYear` was declared `As Integer`, it can't accept a Null ... causing the *"Invalid use of Null"* complaint.

Answer (score 0):

It is very important to put
Option Explicit at the top of each module.
This is flag whenever you use a variable which hasn't been declared.
Like you've done, it's a good idea to have at least one capital letter in every variable.
That way, when you enter  line, you'll know immediately if you've spell each variable correctly as soon as you leave that line.
I always name globals in all capitals - like Public Dim YEARPAST as Long
or Const YEARPAST as Long = 1
Then I know something is a global
I know a lot of coders think globals are a bad idea but they work for me, either at the project level, or in a particular module so I don't have to pass values in variables all the time.  Also, a nice way to communicate information across the project or procedures in a module.

Comment: You recognized the invention of paragraphs and other formating options to increase readability ;) Suggesting `Option Explicit`is a very good idea, but always provide useful links (e.g. [riptutorial.com](https://riptutorial.com/) is a good source). Also there is a reason for the experienced users to warn on unnecessary globals, as you can suffer on weird side-effects. Always use as less scope as possible! Lazyness on setting vars is a very bad habit, usually resulting in much more work to remove the resulting flaws (same on naming).

Comment: Wasn’t looking for stylistic comments on a suggestion really. Just adding your extra info like reference on explicit is sufficient on these boards.